# Writing a custom MSBuild task which contains arbitrary XML

Tags: msbuild

Is this possible? And if so, could I retrieve the raw XML within the Execute method?

```
<MyTask>
    <Arbitrary Xml="Here" />
</MyTask>
```

I suspect the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You suspect correctly :)

You would have to put your XML into a Property and then pass it into the task as all other properties are passed into tasks.